# UK General visitor visa without professional situation, is my husband's situation sufficient?

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, london

My husband is going to UK on a business trip for 4 weeks and I would like to join him on his last week there and return back with him. I am currently a housewife, so I havent got any source of income. All I have in my bank account is my final settlement from my old job (I quit a year ago).

I don't own any property and I haven't got any dependent kids. So I am afraid if they might find this as a reason for rejection since I havent got any "strong ties" with my nation.

My husband will be sponsoring my entire trip and his trip is sponsored by his company. So is it enough to show only his bank statements and that I am dependent on him?

Can anyone please help me as to what all documents I might have to show them so that my application will not be rejected. I am a huge Beatles fan and I just want to visit Liverpool for a week.

Answer (score 3):

The new UK Visitor regime activated yesterday, so you will be in the first tranche of people applying for the [Standard Visitor Visa](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa).

Accordingly, it is vital that you discard information on the net published before 24 April 2015 and read the new [Visitor: supporting documents guide](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/423699/2015_04_20_Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_Final__2__-_CLEAN.pdf).  This guidance contains a list of documents that should be provided.  Helpfully, it also contains a list of things they *do not* want to see.

It is not appropriate to provide a list here on [Travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions), because the required documents will vary according to the applicant's personal circumstances.  If you find the guidance unclear, you can use their [feedback](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/visitor-visa-guide-to-supporting-documents) option to let them know.

They already understand that some spouses are dependants and do not have their own income stream.  This condition, in itself, does not create the grounds for automatic refusal and there is no history of a refusal on these grounds alone.

For your comment about being a Beatles fan, take note that they sometimes find this [suspicious and may ask you for more info](http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/england/merseyside/3173439.stm).  Being able to recognize their songs and recite some lyrics has been helpful for previous visitors.